# Проблемы с volsnap.sys

Tags: windows, windows-7

Довольно часто мой Windows 7 валится с синим экраном, указывающим на `volsnap.sys`. Гугл говорит, что это драйвер теневого копирования. Падения происходят в рандомное время, как при использовании компа, так и в период простоя. Замечал падение при установке конкретного обновления, по возможности систему обновления испортил, но падения не прекратились. После этого включил автоматическую перезагрузку при синем экране, отключил запись дампа памяти (только место занимает) и отключил восстановление системы (гугл говорит, что оно и производит теневое копирование), но проблема не исчезла - перезагрузку с синим экраном я точно видел, но из-за отключенности сохранения дампа он промелькнул слишком быстро и я не успел прочитать сообщение, чтобы убедиться, что ошибка всё та же.

Если считать, что ошибка та же, то что (включая групповые политики) может использовать теневое копирование и как это отключить? Может быть есть другие способы решения?

После синего экрана использование `sfc /scannow` исправляет ошибки.

[image: Фото синего экрана]

Comment: Может стоит сменить систему бэкапа?

Comment: @donRumata, в данном случае устраивает даже отключить её. Только как?

Comment: https://www.ubackup.com/windows-10/volume-shadow-copy-windows-10.html

Comment: Не пробовали ставить чистый образ вин7? Копаться в OC трудоемкое занятие, всегда проще сбросить необходимые данные в облако или на флешку и накатить чистый образ. А потом не беспокоиться о подобных проблемах вовсе..